# How to count distance from Latlng in firebase to my current location Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps

I have 3 markers on maps in my app, this 3 markers location is based on data Latlng in firebase. How can i show a distance from 3 markers to my current location.

This is how i show markers :

```
refDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            LatLng newlocation = new LatLng(dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class),dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class));
            nama = new String(dataSnapshot.child("nama").getValue(String.class));
            kec = new String(dataSnapshot.child("kecamatan").getValue(String.class));
            kab = new String(dataSnapshot.child("kebupaten").getValue(String.class));
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(newlocation).title(nama+", "+kec+", "+kab));

    });
```

If there is a possible way, how can i save all distance in same time to firebase, i have 1 empty child "distance" in firebase.

Comment: search for `android distance beetween 2 points latlng`. You will need ~12 sconds to find an answer. BTW nothing related to firebase and android-studio here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use android.location.Location.distanceBetween() to calculate distances between two locations. It is a location method given by android.
The whole signature is like below :-
distanceBetween (double startLatitude, 
                double startLongitude, 
                double endLatitude, 
                double endLongitude, 
                float[] results)
You can refer to below link for further doubts https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[])